# php if anchor tag is present in URL then change a php code if / else

Tags: php, jquery, anchor, supersized

I am working on a website that i just uploaded to a test area.

http://cascarinosonline.com.216-70-85-163.messtudios.com/

I want to edit the gallery based on an incoming link. Currently I am using supersized jquery pluggin for the gallery.

When you view the gallery now its working as it should, however when you are on the Homepage and you click on "new outside area" on the bottom right corner I want it the link to take you to the gallery page but start on a different slide.

I couldn't find an easy way to do this with supersized jquery plugin... I thought it would be a simple URL anchor tag like so:

http://cascarinosonline.com.216-70-85-163.messtudios.com/gallery.php#slide12

---

So I think this is my solution, the default gallery page is labeled with a php value:

```
<?php $page = "gallery" ; ?>
```

And in my code it says

```
<?php if ($page == "gallery" ) { echo $galleryAll; } ?>
```

$galleryAll; has the list of gallery images in the normal order.....

---

Now, I made a different php code that is:

```
<?php if ($page == "galleryfix" ) { echo $galleryOutside; } ?>
```

Now this $galleryOutside; has the outside image first in the list.

Both examples above work, if I manually change the php page value to equal the content I want.

My Questions is:

I added an anchor tag to the homepage link and it looks like this:

```
http://cascarinosonline.com.216-70-85-163.messtudios.com/gallery.php#outside
```

I want php to find the url and if it has "#outside" then echo $page == "galleryOutside" else $page == "gallery"

I am not sure if this is the best way to do this, but Im pretty positive it will work as long as you can use php to get the incoming link url and change if/else value.

Thanks in advance!
-O

UPDATE: I found this, but not working.

```
<?php 

$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($host == 'cascarinosonline.com.216-70-85-163.messtudios.com/gallery.php#outside') 
{
$page = "gallery";
}
else
{
$page = "galleryfix";
}

;?>
```

Comment: No, this will not work, because the anchor part of the link is handled entirely by the browser, and never gets sent to PHP. The server never sees that part of the link.

Comment: Your right, any other solution... I am still searching and will post here once I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

I ditched the php method, and used jquery to find the hash tag and to take the proper action inside the gallery.

```js
if (window.location.hash == "#outside") {
  $(".slide-11").addClass("activeslide");
}
```